# Exception from NinjectMvcHttpApplicationPlugin via Ninject.MVC3 Bootstrapper (in MVC4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I know there are some questions already on this topic but I am still missing something that is causing this error. I installed ninject.mvc3 package which installs ninject and ninject.web.common packages. No modification was made in global.asax (as suggested in official documentation).

`App_Start/NinjectWebCommon.cs`'s `RegisterServices` method has the `Bind` statement after loading the `Kernel`. I am getting this error with this stack trace when I try to run the site.

```
[InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements]
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +379
   Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectMvcHttpApplicationPlugin.Start() in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectMvcHttpApplicationPlugin.cs:53
   Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map(IEnumerable`1 series, Action`1 action) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Infrastructure\Language\ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.cs:32
   Ninject.Web.Common.Bootstrapper.Initialize(Func`1 createKernelCallback) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Ninject.Web.Common\src\Ninject.Web.Common\Bootstrapper.cs:53
   Ninject.Web.Common.NinjectHttpApplication.Application_Start() in c:\Projects\Ninject\Ninject.Web.Common\src\Ninject.Web.Common\NinjectHttpApplication.cs:81

[HttpException (0x80004005): Sequence contains no elements]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +12864673
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +175
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +404
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +475

[HttpException (0x80004005): Sequence contains no elements]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12881540
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12722601
```

What step am I still missing?

Comment: Did it used to work?  Did you recently add a new project to your solution?  This is sort of a generic error that happens when .NET has an error enumerating the types. This is often caused by more than one copy of Ninject in the same namespace.

Comment: @MystereMan I did not install those packages when I created the MVC4 application first time. I added my entity classes (doing code first approach), service layer and then added ninject only to the website layer and not to all projects. I checked there is only one copy of ninject. Are there any steps that have to be done if adding ninject at a later time?

Answer (score 0):

[The source](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/blob/master/mvc3/src/Ninject.Web.Mvc/NinjectMvcHttpApplicationPlugin.cs) says on line 53:

```
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Remove(
    ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.OfType<DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider>)
    .Single());
```

Have you in some way inhibited the addition of the `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider` ? Probably not - therefore I suggest you've got two copies of the same logic in your system - do you have >1 `NinjectWebCommon.cs` ?

Another thing worth trying (in general - I have no specif reason why it should fix this case for you) is see if the same thing still happens when you use the **Include Prerelease** NuGet packages.

Comment: I recalled that I had read in some places that ninject had to be installed before any code is written. Adding it later caused similar kinds of problems is what I read. So I created a new MVC4 project, installed ninject packages as before and then added my code back to it one by one and this time it worked!

So two questions come to my mind.
1. Do we have to do this before any code is written? If yes, what could be the reasoning.
2. If no, are there special steps that need to be done for adding ninject at a later time?

Comment: @user1408865 No, both of those are conspiracy theories I reckon. You should be able to tell the problem from your VCS diffs?

Comment: I'd like to agree with you @RubenBartelink, but having also had to recreate the project myself based on the same error (MVC5/Ninject 3.2) I'm starting to believe in a conspiracy.